# CheckSUR (System Update Readiness Tool) --- (log+screencast)

Tags: windows-7, windows

Having stubborn corruption issues on my Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.

I have tried hard to solve this for almost 2 weeks now, without success..
I'm a bit surprised/offended to find myself being forced to resort to specialized forums like this one to fix my problem because I usually always find a way of my own. But this time I will need you guys.

I'm fairly good at digging into Windows OS so I'll be able to follow your instruction very easily, without having you to be extremely detailed and to describe any common IT terms.

## Problem

- Corrupt system files which leads to problem installing/uninstalling applications, windows update, ssd firmware, basically anything that require deeper system's integration.
- sfc scan find corrupt files but can't fix them all.

## Troubleshoot done so far

- Scanned for presence of any malwares/virus/rootkit.  Result --> none
- Uninstalled/Reinstalled corrupt applications         Result --> Sucess, but had to uninstall the dirty way (Revo uninstaller and manual registry left-over removal)
- Installed all missing .NET Framework & Visual C++ Redistributables
- Registry scan/clean (CCleaner, Little Registry Cleaner, and such)   Result --> Many problem found/fixed, without real improvement.
- sfc scan (`sfc /scannow`)
- checkdisk scan (`chkdsk /f /v /r /x /b`)
- Reset system's default permission using Tweaking.com's tools (and some manual manipulation)

## Generated logs: list of all generated log files (all done with elevated administrator privilege):

- sfc scan       ---> https://www.dropbox.com/s/h24h371z1ynjgxv/sfc%20scan%20log.txt
- chkdsk scan    ---> https://www.dropbox.com/s/7e45yw9e7j9dpgw/chkdsk.txt
- OTL scan       ---> can't complete a scan because of infinite loop on the AppData directory ---> http://screencast.com/t/C83Rut1Bnqgt
- CheckSUR ---> can't install the System Update Readiness Tool either but was able to get some log: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ld02wwmlv1b8k7n/CbsPersist_20140313224512.cab
- SFCFix 2.1.4.0 by niemiro --> https://www.dropbox.com/s/3xtnphhfszt7x5u/SFCFix.txt

I would at least like to be able to install CheckSUR ...

I can extract the content of the installer... is there something I can do with those extracted file ? I tried but its a mess of multiple cab files...

Comment: There are some missing system files that need to be restored. Could you compress the original `CBS.log` and `CheckSUR.log` files into an archive and upload them?

Answer (score 0):

You have several corrupetd files which can't be restored:

```
2014-03-13 12:42:13, Info                  CSI    0000031e [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:18{9}]"MSDTC.LOG" of Microsoft-Windows-COM-DTC-Runtime, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:13, Info                  CSI    0000031f [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Quirky, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:13, Info                  CSI    00000320 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Sonata, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:13, Info                  CSI    00000321 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Characters, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:13, Info                  CSI    00000322 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Heritage, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:13, Info                  CSI    00000323 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Savanna, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:13, Info                  CSI    00000324 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Festival, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:13, Info                  CSI    00000325 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Afternoon, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:13, Info                  CSI    00000326 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Landscape, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    00000327 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Cityscape, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    00000328 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Raga, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    00000329 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Landscape, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    0000032a [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.Personalization"
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    0000032b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Cityscape, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    0000032c [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.Personalization"
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    0000032d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Quirky, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    0000032e [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.Personalization"
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    0000032f [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Sonata, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    00000330 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.Personalization"
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    00000331 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Characters, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    00000332 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.Personalization"
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    00000333 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Savanna, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    00000334 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.Personalization"
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    00000335 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Heritage, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    00000336 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.Personalization"
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    00000337 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:18{9}]"MSDTC.LOG" of Microsoft-Windows-COM-DTC-Runtime, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:14, Info                  CSI    00000338 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:202{101}]"Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.WindowsFoundationDelivery"
2014-03-13 12:42:15, Info                  CSI    00000339 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Festival, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:15, Info                  CSI    0000033a [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.Personalization"
2014-03-13 12:42:15, Info                  CSI    0000033b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Raga, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:15, Info                  CSI    0000033c [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.Personalization"
2014-03-13 12:42:15, Info                  CSI    0000033d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"Desktop.ini" of Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Afternoon, Version = 6.1.7600.16385, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, file is missing
2014-03-13 12:42:15, Info                  CSI    0000033e [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Shell-SoundThemes-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514.Personalization"
```

In Windows Vista/7 you can only fix it by doing an [Inplace upgrade](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html).

- Boot into Windows and put the Windows DVD into your drive or mount an ISO of Win7
- Open the DVD drive and run setup.exe
- Select "Upgrade" in the installer

[image]

Comment: I can only see MSDTC.LOG & Desktop.ini missing.. couldn't I simply restore them from a previous backup I've made on an external drive ?

If not. What will I loose making an in-place upgrade ?

thanks

Comment: you loose nothing. All applications will stay.

Comment: @dwsck "you can only fix it by doing an Inplace upgrade": not really, missing files can be manually restored. Granted, an in-place upgrade might fix *other* issues as well.

Comment: @and31416 & magicandre1981
Just wanted to drop by for a quick "sorry" at you guys for not replying at you at the time.. I just noticed how popular the post got over time, which got me as well to realize that I didn't even took the time to reply at you.. Sorry about that. Also, thanks and31416 for the markdown formatting.

Mods: Unfortunately, I can't update those deadlinks in OP, feel free to supress this thread if you feel the need to.

Comment: @GnstheGrain have you ever tried the repair? Does Windows work now? Or have you done the upgrade to Win10?

Comment: @magicandre1981 It's been 2+ years so I don't remember the outcome, but i'm pretty sure I got it sorted out. It's a shame that I didn't update this post with it. As for Win10, it's a NOGO for me :) Still on a Win7, which I still appreciate (once tweaked properly). 

One thing for sure is that I didn't go the "reset/repair/restore"-way. I never did.. so I guess that I've found some solution.

Comment: and sfc now reports that everything is fine?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes (well.. not exactly because `SFC` detect some of my personal system tweaks (modified configs) as corrupted, (so i always write-protect those file before initiating any sort of system file integrity check such as `SFC`. But as far as this thread is concerned, yes I actually managed to find my way and everything run perfectly, and yes, I'm still using the very same machine and OS since OP =)